# Apache SSL set maximum fragment length

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, buffer, maxlength

Working on an embedded device where RAM is a luxury,
I would like to configure SSL on Apache to set the maximum TLS record size.
RFC says that the tls record size must be 16K,  but the [tls extension](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3546.txt) says that the client can send along with its hello the requested length.

In Openssl there is a function that lets me configure it.
It can be configured with the use of these macros.  [ssl.h](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_1-stable/ssl/ssl.h#L2162)

Is there a way to configure Apache to set the maximum fragment length withouth having to recompile apache and openssl?

Using Apache 2.22.22 and openssl 1.01i

Comment: Did you find a satisfactory solution to this problem?  I'm running into something very similar using a GainSpan client - also embedded and RAM restricted.

Answer (score 0):

First I doubt that it makes sense to use Apache on a system which is as much resource constraint that you need to restrict the TLS fragment size. Apart from that this is a setting on the client side, that is the resource constraint client can request a lower then usual fragment size, see [RFC 6066](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066#page-8):

> In order to negotiate smaller maximum fragment lengths, clients MAY include an extension of type "max_fragment_length" in the (extended) client hello.

Thus setting this extension inside Apache would only make sense if used as a proxy and would not affect the part where Apache is the server.

Comment: Sorry, I have not explained correctly. The embedded system is the client and it has limited ram so I need to decrease the ssl buffer size. Already done, but when the response is bigger that the size of the ssl buffer on the client side then it does not work and my ssl stack receives invalid records. So I must set the same tls fragment size also at the sirver side. Apache runs on a modern high end machine. I already send the extension but I think that the server ignores it. As the RFC says the server MAY accept it, maybe not.

Comment: Looking at the code of OpenSSL 1.02 it looks like that it ignores this TLS extension. And while OpenSSL offers an API to set this value (SSL_CTX_set_max_send_fragment) I don't think Apache uses it, so recompiling will not help. You would not only recompile but also patch apache to support this feature.